# Path problem when chain-run applications ElectronJS, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, electron

I'm building an application using ElectronJS for myself to open various applications.

When I run from `app1` an `app2`, which also runs `app3`, `app2` can no longer find `app3` because the path has been changed to `app1`'s directory and if I move `app3` to `app1`'s directory, `app2` can find `app3`.

Also if I run `app2` directly by double clicking on `app2.exe` it runs `app3` without a problem.

The app list looks like this:

```
const appList = {
    app1: `${path.join(exepath, '..')}\\381637ea\\2ab88db2\\app1.exe}`,
    app2: `${path.join(exepath, '..')}\\e23bf9a0\\698700a7\\app2.exe}`, //app2.exe runs bin64/app3.exe
}
```

And I'm executing like this:

```
shell.openExternal(appList.app2);
```

I tried using `path.resolve` but it did not help.

I remember having the same issue in the C# application.
Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

Thank you

Comment: Where populates your `exepath` variable and do your ‘app#.exe’ path(s) change? Those ‘hex style’ folder names look rather transient.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Folder names are set manually, paths are not changing.

Comment: Just trying to get an understanding of your requirement. Are the app(s), Electron applications? And is each application able to open the other 2 applications? You mention ‘chain-run' in your title. Is that meaning; to open the designated applications in sequence. Just trying to figure out if it is a path problem or a sequential promise problem when using `shell.openExternal(url[, options])`

Comment: In "chain-run" I mean when you run an application that runs another application automatically. Thank you for trying to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. So if anyone will have the same issue, the solution is CWD or Current Working Directory.
In `app1` you need to pass the `workingDirectory` argument and `app2` will understand where is its own working directory to run `app3` from there:

```
shell.openExternal(appList.app2, 
            {workingDirectory: path.dirname(appList.app2)});
```